# C# Linq, Searching for same items in two lists

Tags: c#, linq

we have the following setup:
We have a array of objects with a string in it (xml-ish but not normalized) and we have a list/array of strings with id.

We need to find out if a string from that list with id's is also pressent in one of the objects.

Here we have a setup that we have tried:

```
public class Wrapper
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Wrapper> wrappers = new List<Wrapper>() 
        {
            new Wrapper{ MyProperty = "<flkds,dlsklkdlsqkdkqslkdlqk><id>3</id><sqjldkjlfdskjlkfjsdklfj>"}, 
            new Wrapper{ MyProperty = "<flkds,dlsklkdlsqkdkqslkdlqk><id>2</id><sqjldkjlfdskjlkfjsdklfj>"}
        };
        string[] ids = { "<id>0</id>", "<id>1</id>", "<id>2</id>" };

        var props = wrappers.Select(w => w.MyProperty);
        var intersect = props.Intersect(ids, new MyEquilityTester());
        Debugger.Break();
    }
}

class MyEquilityTester: IEqualityComparer<string>
{
    public bool Equals(string x, string y)
    {
        return x.Contains(y);
    }

     public int GetHashCode(string obj)
     {
         return obj.GetHashCode();
     }
 }
```

Edit:

What we expect is when we do a `.Any()` on `intersect` that is says `true` because wrappers has a object with a prop that contains `<id>2</id>`, `intersect` is `null`.

If we are using the wrong method please say. It should work as fast as posible. A simple `true` when found will do!

Comment: The best thing to do here is parse the text in `MyProperty` to a more readable/linq-friendly/maintainable structure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For your case, you could write your `IEqualitycomparer` like this:

```
class MyEquilityTester: IEqualityComparer<string>
{
    public bool Equals(string x, string y)
    {
        return x.Contains(y) || y.Contains(x);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(string obj)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

and it will find

```
<flkds,dlsklkdlsqkdkqslkdlqk><id>2</id><sqjldkjlfdskjlkfjsdklfj>
```

This works because `GetHashCode` always return `0`, and the  `x.Contains(y) || y.Contains(x)` check.

---

Another not-so-hacky solution is to use a `Where` in combination with `Any`

```
IEnumerable<String> intersect = props.Where(p => ids.Any (i => p.Contains(i)));
```

or replace the `Where` with another `Any` if you don't care about the actual items and you only want a `true` or `false`.

```
bool intersect = props.Any(p => ids.Any (i => p.Contains(i)));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
wrappers.Where(w=>ids.Any(i=>w.MyProperty.Contains(i)))
```